# How to access TrackPad device in eeepc?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, eee-pc

I am on an Eeepc running Ubuntu and I am trying to store the raw data from the Eeepc's inbuilt track pad in a file.

To do this with the keyboard (as root) I went

```
cat /dev/input/event7 > ~/raw-keyboard-out.data
```

The result was the whole bunch of random-looking data I was hoping for.

Now I want to do this for my mouse, and I tried all of the 'files' in this folder in an analogous operation and none of them seem to stream the input into a file.

Does anybody know what the name of the TrackPad/mouse device is called in the /dev folder for an Asus Eeepc 1001p?

The hope is eventually to manipulate the data and stream it to one of the output devices in /dev

Answer (score 0):

All pointer devices are multiplexed to `/dev/input/mice`. If you want the specific device node for the trackpad then you will need to poke through `/sys`, specifically `/sys/bus` and/or `/sys/class/input`.